# repeating-linear-gradient not working in Edge browser and internet Explorer Browser

Tags: html, css

I am making a project. I am using `repeating-linear-gradient` on my website for style.

I am use below style(CSS) for the style:

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,#74C374 12px 15px,#5CB85C 10px 20px) 0 0/100% 100% no-repeat;
background-size: 4% 100%;
```

Using above css I am generation this style:

[image: Style]

Above style is **working fine in Chrome browser but not in Internet Explorer browser and Edge browse**

Comment: repeating-linear-gradient is not supported in Edge & IE. check this link: 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient

Comment: I am trying this but it will takes whole td.

Comment: Background size is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply this and check

```
background-size: 4% 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #74C374, #74C374 5px, #5CB85C 5px, #5CB85C 10px);
        background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #74C374 12px 15px, #5CB85C 10px 20px);
```